# How to save retrofit response in shared preferences in and use it repository layer

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, sharedpreferences

I have post method where I am sending login request to server but first I want to save that response using shared preferences in my repository how can save retrofit response in shared preferences

below my interface class I have implemented login post request logic

```
interface MeloApi {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/login")
    suspend fun makeLogin(@Body loginModel: LoginModel) : Response<LoginModel>



}
```

below my loginModel class

```
data class LoginModel(
    val userName:String,
    val password:String)
```

below LoginResponse.kt

```
data class LoginResponse(
    @SerializedName("accessToken")
    val accessToken: String,
    @SerializedName("refreshToken")
    val refreshToken: String,
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status: String,
    @SerializedName("user")
    val user: User
)
```

below my Interceptor

```
class HeaderInterceptor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager
) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        request = request.newBuilder()
            .header("refreshToken", tokenManager.refreshToken.toString())
            .header("accessToken", tokenManager.accessToken.toString())
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

below my token manager

```
class TokenManager {
    var accessToken: String? = null
    var refreshToken: String? = null
}
```

below my appModule.kt

```
val apiModule = module {
    single {
        TokenManager()
    }

    single {
        HeaderInterceptor(get())
    }

    single {
        val httpInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(
                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor(get()))
                    .addInterceptor(httpInterceptor).build()
            )
//           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
            .create(MeloApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

below my LoginRepository

```
class LoginRepository(
    private val meloApi: MeloApi
) {
    suspend fun login(loginModel: LoginModel) {
        GlobalScope.launch {


            val response = meloApi.makeLogin(loginModel)
            response.isSuccessful
            val userName = response.body()?.userName
            val password = response.body()?.password
            loginRequest(userName, password)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun loginRequest(userName: String?, password: String?){




    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store as object you have to use serialization/deserialization.

I used [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) here.

```
        val loginResponse = LoginResponse("AToken", "RToken", "200", User("Edgar"))
        val objToString = Gson().toJson(loginResponse)

        
        
        val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("loginRes", MODE_PRIVATE)
        sharedPref.edit().putString("response", objToString).apply()

        val response = sharedPref.getString("response", "null")
        val stringToObj = Gson().fromJson(response, LoginResponse::class.java)
```

You can use [proto datastore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#proto-datastore) instead of shared preferences.